# Python regular expression gives unexpected result

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create an svn pre-commit hook, but can't get my regular expression to work as expected. It should print `False` for messages that do not look like "DEV-5 | some message". Why do I get True here?

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile("^\[[A-Z]+-[0-9]+\] | .+$", re.DOTALL)
>>> message = "test message"
>>> match = p.search(message)
>>> bool(match)
True
```

Comment: pipe character | should be escaped with \

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> p = re.compile("^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+ \| .+$", re.DOTALL)
>>> print p.search("test message")
None
>>> print p.search("DEV-5 | some message")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x800eb78b8>
```

- you don't need `\[` and `\]`
- you need to escape `|`

Comment: Thank you, that was it. `\[` is a copy/paste from another script and I completely forgot about excaping `|`.

Answer (score 4):

The culprit is the trailing " | .+$" which is matching ' message' as an alternative to the first regex. As Roman pointed out you meant to match literal '|' so you have to escape it as '\|'.

To see what was being matched, you can do:

```
print match.group()
' message'
```

(By the way, a faster non-regex way to only handle lines containing vertical bar would use line.split('|'):

```
for line in ...:
   parts = line.split('|',1)
   if len(parts)==1: continue
   (code,mesg) = parts
```

Comment: Your example using split will break for any line that doesn't contain `|`. There will only be a single element in the result so you'll get `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: Fixed. The usual idiom when we don't know how many parts *`split()`* will return is to assign its result to a sequence, then test the sequence length. (Or else catch the exception - less preferred). There is another clever idiom [here](http://opensourcehacker.com/2010/04/17/how-to-split-strings-of-indefined-item-count-to-python-variables-elegantly/) which appends [None] * n to the *`split()`* result to ensure the result tuple is full..

Comment: Appending `[None]*n` usually gets quite messy, but actually in this case it wouldn't be too bad: `code,mesg,*junk = line.split('|',1) + [None]` though I still prefer the code as you have it now.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run the code, but I suspect that the part after the alternative (`|`) in your regexp matches any nonempty string starting with a space, in this case it's `" message"`.